# Adaptive threshold return empty characters

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

When I adaptive threshold an image, in some cases it returns empty characters. I am looking for a solution, maybe some preprocessing to prevent this. Here are some examples. (photo from google)

[image]

and the result:
[image]

I want something like the small size numbers (0123... - which are solid).
It also happens when we have light characters on dark background!
Thank you.

edit: here is a number on dark bg. I used a large kernel size but it is not resolved.

[image]

[image]

Comment: For larger font size, you need to use larger kernel size

Comment: Main problem is light chars on dark background!

Comment: Then adaptive thresholding is probably the wrong tool for the job. Please do not use the [tag:cv2] tag. As the description says, "THIS TAG IS PENDING REMOVAL."

Comment: Your kernel has to be larger than the stroke width of the letters. But as said above, none of these images need adaptive thresholding. Your backgrounds are all uniform.

Comment: @CrisLuengo It is just an example. Actual images have complex backgrounds...

Comment: I recommend that you provide *meaningful* examples when asking a question. I've seen a lot of unsatisfactory answers on here because the examples given in the question turned out to not be representative. Then you get this ugly back and forth where asker keeps updating their question and answerer gets frustrated with the moving goalposts.

Comment: @Saeide you could try finding sufficiently large contours after adaptive threshold